# Codename one application lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I am android developer, and I was faced with the task to try to "migrate" on "Codename one." Not at will. On Android there is a very clear description of the life cycle from Google. In Codename one as stating that the life cycle is more like a desktop application. And so I'm wondering if there is a stage of the life cycle of analogues, such as onPause and onSaveInstanceState in Codename one. Or will have to do an insert platform code?

Answer (score 4):

Codename One has `init/start/stop/destroy` which are pretty similar although simpler than Androids lifecycle. `stop()` will be invoked to pause, `start()` will be reinvoked for resume.

Comment: Is there some comprehensive documentation on `Form` lifecycle, like under what circumstances `beforeForm()` gets invoked, or where to place code necessary to populate a `Form` evey time it's viewed?

Comment: That's the GUI builder and its unrelated to app lifecycle as covered by this answer. You need to use the before form to populate the form every time.

Comment: But Shai, I am experiencing an issue I saw many other developers had, as well: the `beforeShow()` only gets called the first time a Form is shown.

Comment: Still unrelated to lifecycle. If you show the form correctly beforeShow should get invoked.

Comment: Let's continue in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/beforeForm$20not$20called/codenameone-discussions/Tcp0FP2ay14/lpYTh6O29BAJ)